# Java alphabets in different languages

Tags: java, string, localization

How can I determine if String contains only alphabets and I want to have little more than [a-zA-Z]+, so is there any way to determine alphabets by Locale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Character`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class has methods such as [`isLetter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) which will be able to determine if a character is a letter as defined in the API specification for the method.

There is also another approach of using the [`Character.UnicodeBlock`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) class which is able to return whether a character is in a specific character block of [Unicode](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FUnicode&ei=btX6ScaQE9SSkAXds4nrBA&rct=j&q=unicode&usg=AFQjCNH4Pwv5L_jFFLS8yq6_BTq8cXTLKw).

For example, I had to determine whether a character was a full-width [katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana) character, and to be able to do so, I had to use the [`Character.UnicodeBlock.of`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#of(char)) method:

```
boolean isKatakana = 
    Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.KATAKANA;
```

Also to add, the character at a certain index of a `String` can be retrieved by using the [`charAt(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) method, and the Unicode code point can be retrieved by the [`codePointAt(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) method.

Answer (score 1):

In addition take a look at com.ibm.icu.text package. For example, this snippet returns all alphabet letters for defined language:

```
ULocale ulocale = com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale
    .forLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(language));
UnicodeSet set = LocaleData.getExemplarSet(ulocale, LocaleData.ES_STANDARD);
Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  buf.append(iterator.next());

}
return buf.toString();
```

This task cannot be reached by the means of java.* packages.