# How do I divide name strings beginning with different language specific characters

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, localization

How do I divide name strings beginning with different language specific characters?

Seems an easy question, but unless you know your way it's kind of hard!

I wish to do this without any extra utility library. Can it be done with just String class?

SORRY (idiot Me!) LET ME REPHRASE IT:

I have contact names in a phone book. Some of them are Hebrew/Arabic some of them are Chineese, and some are English. I want to dissect these names in to ones that start with each language.

What String utility should I use for that?

Comment: You can divide two numbers and you can split a string with any characters.  Can you demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the String class. Create a regex with the characters you want to be used for splitting and use `String.split(regex)`

Comment: I asked wrongly.. I mean to dissect a list of names to ones that start with english/hebrew/... (split into different groups - see my edit^^)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

This is something called [Unicode Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block)
And I followed the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810954/java-alphabets-in-different-languages?rq=1)